# Getting one Field prior to an atomic update in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, atomic, mongoengine

Assuming a schema like below:

```
class DocA(Document):
    owner = ReferenceField(User)
    strings = ListField(StringField)
```

If I want to check if the logged in user is the owner and then add a new string to stringlist, I currently have to access the database twice:

```
if self.has_perm(DocA.objects(id=someid).only('owner').first()):
    DocA.objects(id=someid).update_one(push__strings="New String")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can `self.has_perm` be defined in a query?  Looks like its 3 queries.
1) Get DocA, 2) Get User 3) Update

Comment: `self.has_perm` does not query the database at all. It just checks if the object_passed_to_it.owner.username is equal to the logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given has perm is just checking the owner you can do this in a single query:

```
DocA.objects(id=someid, user=logged_in_user).update_one(push__strings="New String")
```

Comment: In the query above, logged_in_user would have to be a Document instance, rather than a username. user__username does not seem to work, though.